# Javascript | Html canvas error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to "draw" a rectangle in a black canvas but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  draw();
}

function draw() {
  canvasContext.fillstyle='black';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,800,600);
  canvasContext.fillstyle='white';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,10,10);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hello - what doesn't work specifically?  Does it show anything?

Comment: It's **not** the problem, but: That code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables at the appropriate scope. In this case, I would probably remove the `onload` handler and instead just put all of your code in a scoping function in a `script` at the end of the HTML, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: canvasContext will not be accessible in draw function

Comment: @PranayKumar: Yes, it will (and is).

Comment: **It's just a typo**, `fillstyle` should be `fillStyle` (capital S). Voting to close as typo/non-repro. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used lowercase "s" instead of uppercase "S" in fillstyle

Change

```
canvasContext.fillstyle
```

to

```
canvasContext.fillStyle
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');


  draw();

}

function draw() {
  canvasContext.fillStyle='black';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,800,600);
  canvasContext.fillStyle='white';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,100,100);


}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: But moreover, typos don't need answers, just comments and (when you can) close votes. Posting an answer can prevent the OP deleting the question, which is the right course of action as it's not useful to others in the future (and could force them to accept rep loss from downvotes).

Comment: The time to explain is *as* you're writing the answer, not after posting it.

Comment: i am sorry friend, i am not an active stack overflow user dont know the rules much, just started answering questions a few weeks ago